# authentication using httplib in python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, httplib

I am using python 2.7.10. How can I login using httplib connection method.

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("192.18.33.10")
conn.request("POST", "/user/user.form?name=Maharjun&age=23")
res = conn.getresponse()    
data = res.read()
```

**What this user.form does is**, it will accept some details like name and age from users and server will save them in database. This details can only filled by authenticated users.

I tried some suggestions from python http.requests but those are not working in python-2.7.10.

I know about postman. So, I sent same request in postman using basic authentication method and i converted that into python scripts. In postman we can convert postman-URL into curl/shell/python scripts. So, I converted them into python scripts.

**Both are same requests. But I am able to submit the data using postman. But not able to do with python.**

postman is giving me a post-man token and basic authentication in headers like below code. is there any mistakes in the code or any suggestions?

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("192.18.33.10")
url = "/user/user.form?name=Maharjun&age=23"
headers = {
    'authorization': "Basic some-token",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "some-token"
    }
response = conn.request("POST", url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Though it have ***'authorization'*** token I was not able to login by using above code.

can someone help me to write basic authentication using python requests.?

Comment: You're not saying what the server is requiring. If it's a simple authentication form, which looks like it since you're trying a POST to a user/login/ API, then you should post a username/password as form data (and I'd hope the URL would be HTTPS, not HTTP).
If it's HTTP Basic Authentication, then I'd expect a HTTP GET request to some URL that requires authentication via HTTP headers.

Comment: I am sending "authorization" from headers. But I don't want to take that from post-man. I want to send username and password. how can I send them in headers?. in previous python version we used "auth=('username','password')". Like this, in 2.7.10 version how can i send them?

Comment: I still don't understand what the server is expecting. I don't believe a POST to a /user/login/ url requires login details (username/password) in HTTP headers, but actually wants them in the post data. Tell us more about the server.

Comment: Sorry. I did not give more details. I am adding additional details. can you recheck the question?

Comment: You say _These details can only be filled by authenticated users_ but how do users authenticate in the first place? username/password? How did you authenticate to do the postman request? You say _basic authentication method_ was that HTTP basic authentication? It's that authentication you need to achieve in your script, not a _replay_ of postman